# SpringBoot using Jigsaw module for java9

Tags: spring-boot, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to write a simple spring boot application that I can run using Java 9. I am unable to compile this application under jdk9.
I get bunch of error around logging modules

Does anyone have any sample application that is using Springboot under jdk9 jigsaw concept ?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project JigsawTest: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] the unnamed module reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.aop reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.context reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.beans reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.jcl reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.boot.starter.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.boot.starter reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.boot.starter.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module logback.classic reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module logback.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module slf4j.api reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module jcl.over.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module jul.to.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module log4j.over.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.boot.starter.tomcat reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module tomcat.embed.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module tomcat.embed.el reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module tomcat.embed.websocket reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module hibernate.validator reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module validation.api reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module jboss.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module classmate reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module jackson.databind reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module jackson.annotations reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module jackson.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.webmvc reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.expression reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.boot reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
[ERROR] module spring.boot.autoconfigure reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both spring.jcl and jcl.over.slf4j
```

[Here is the link to my sample project in github](https://github.com/jsaraiya1/JigsawTest)

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Some obvious questions: what version of Maven are you using? Can you share the pom.xml? What version of Spring Boot are you working with?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like:

1. all the JARs end up on the module path (weird)
2. *spring.jcl* and *jcl.over.slf4j* contain an awful lot of the same packages

If you can't fix 1., try solving 2. by excluding one of the two artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get to the example to compile [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_32_stack_overflow_45600351). At this point `mvn clean package` works using Maven 3.5.0. Please note that I have not tried to run the app.

Note that I made the following changes:

Per convention, the source-code now resides in a folder that matches the module name.

```
~/com.allstate.jigsaw/src/main/java/...
```

The `module-info.java` file has been simplified:

```
module com.allstate.jigsaw {
    requires java.logging;

    requires spring.boot;
}
```

Also the, `pom.xml` has been revamped to use Java 9. There is a parent `pom.xml` in the root, and another in the module folder. Here is the main dependency, in `com.allstate.jigsaw/pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the help. However, running this requires some additional work. I had to exclude org.slf4j in spring-boot-starter artifact to get it going.